# Set alarm on particular days

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7

I am facing problem with local notification. I want to use them to set an alarm on particular days. I have used this code.

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitCalendar | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute;
```

Please help me with this stuff.
Suggestions accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you kindly reformat the question?

Comment: Do you want the notification to repeat each day or on a number of days but not consecutive days?

Comment: localNotification.fireDate = @"Your Particular date";

Comment: My question is: I am select on monday,friday,sunday at 11:30 AM. so notification trigger only three days at same time not all days.